# linear independency for homogenous second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can't figure out if this set of equations are linear independent or linear dependent.

$$\{\sin(t)+2\cos(t), \sin(t)-2\cos(t), 2\sin(t)+\cos(t), 2\sin(t)-\cos(t)\}$$

The linear independent theorem states:
 $k_1y_1(t) + k_2y_2(t)+\cdots+ k_ny_n(t) = 0$

if $k_1,\ldots,k_n$(constants) are all equal to 0, they are linear independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\sin(t)+2\cos(t)) + (\sin(t)-2\cos(t)) -\frac{1}{2}(2\sin(t) + \cos(t))-\frac{1}{2}(2\sin(t) - \cos(t))=0$